# JOGL Native Crash

Tags: jogl, crash-reports

I am running a JOGL based application, and it has been crashing when I perform certain drawing operations. However, The line it crashes on is a call to `gl.glGenLists(1)`, so I'm not really sure how this could cause an error in the underlying application, since this line is a trivial line (unless the stack is in some sort of bad state - is that possible?).

I also tried updating my video card drivers and now it just freezes in the same place instead of crashing.

The relevant part of the crash report is below. Any help would be appreciated. I'm running an NVIDIA Quadro NVS 160M video card. Thanks.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6dd7ccac, pid=5520, tid=5684
#
# JRE version: 6.0_16-b01
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (14.2-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [nvoglnt.dll+0x23ccac]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x692c4c00):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=5684, stack(0x696f0000,0x69740000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x00040008

Registers:
EAX=0x6d360798, EBX=0x6e562ffc, ECX=0x00040000, EDX=0xffffffff
ESP=0x6973ee1c, EBP=0x0000000d, ESI=0x6d360650, EDI=0x6d362311
EIP=0x6dd7ccac, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x6973ee1c)
0x6973ee1c:   00001343 00000014 00001344 6e563040
0x6973ee2c:   00000000 6d362310 00000040 7ffad000
0x6973ee3c:   6dd7cdb8 6e562ffc 00001343 6e3c7540
0x6973ee4c:   6dc792a8 00000014 6dbdb13b 00000001
0x6973ee5c:   6e3c7540 6d620000 6973ee90 6dc06fb8
0x6973ee6c:   6d620000 6e3c7540 00000001 692c4c00
0x6973ee7c:   63e576a0 63d38030 6b6c4c0e 00000001
0x6973ee8c:   0ab4f368 6973eeb8 010669c7 692c4d10 

Instructions: (pc=0x6dd7ccac)
0x6dd7cc9c:   00 8b 4b 08 8b 7b 04 89 79 04 8b 4b 04 8b 7b 08
0x6dd7ccac:   89 79 08 0f 84 8c 00 00 00 8b 4c 24 14 8b 7c d1 


Stack: [0x696f0000,0x69740000],  sp=0x6973ee1c,  free space=315k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [nvoglnt.dll+0x23ccac]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  com.sun.opengl.impl.GLImpl.glGenLists0(I)I
...I omitted the rest of the stack, as this is the offending line ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the stack it seems to be nvoglnt.dll that is causing the trouble. Have you absolutely definitely installed the correct driver for your graphics device?

Comment: looks like it was actually a programming error causing an overflow...i was mistakenly generating hundreds of lists in every one of my frame renderings rather than generating the list once and then redrawing it ...oops

Comment: That would explain it. It's a poor system that responds to an attempt to allocate too many lists by crashing, though. Were you attempting to use the list without checking to see if it was a valid return?